# Getting country using GetLocaleInfo Example

Tags: delphi, winapi, pascal

I am trying to get Country in Delphi using GetLocalInfo in Delphi.

I have this code

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
  pcLCA:Array[0..20] of Char;
  country : String;
  Flag: Integer;

begin
    country := GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, Flag, pcLCA,19);
    showmessage(country);
end;

end.
```

But here is the main issue, When i run it, i am getting this as error

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(33): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Integer'
```

on the GetLocaleInfo Line Please what am I not doing correctly. New to this.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [GetLocaleInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfow)?

Answer (score 1):

[GetGeoInfo **return value**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getgeoinfow#return-value) is **int** which is incompatible with **string**.